# Passing a math operator as a parameter

Tags: javascript

I'd like to write a function in Javascript that allows me to pass in a mathematical operator and a list of ints and for each item in that list, apply the operator to it.

Thinking of it in terms of a sum, this is what I've come up with:

```
function accumulate(list, operator){
    var sum = 0;
    for each(var item in list){
        sum = accumulator(sum, item);
    }
    print(sum);
}
```

Testing this code produces the following error:

```
var list = new Array();
list[0] = 1;
list[1] = 2;
list[2] = 3;
```

```
js> accumulate(list, +);
js: "<stdin>", line 9: syntax error
js: accumulate(list, +);
js: ..................^
js: "<stdin>", line 9: Compilation produced 1 syntax errors.
```

Comment: I'd pass it as a string, then determine the passed string in the function and e.g use a switch construct to do the corresponding operation.

Comment: Operators can't be passed like that, and they can't generally be substited by variables, so operators suck that way.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but instead of implementing fold yourself maybe look at the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: remove each keyword from your loop

Comment: why not just pass a string as the operation and check the string before performing the operation?

Comment: Why not use the Array.reduce method?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can't pass an operator as a parameter, but you can pass a function:

```
function accumulate(list, accumulator){   // renamed parameter
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){ // removed deprecated for…each loop
        sum = accumulator(sum, list[i]);
    }
    print(sum);
}

accumulate(list, function(a, b) { return a + b; });
```

This is pretty close to what the [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function does, though not exactly. To mimic the behavior of `reduce`, you'd have to get the first element from `list` and use that as the seed for your accumulator, rather than always using 0:

```
function accumulate(list, accumulator, seed){
    var i = 0, len = list.length;
    var acc = arguments.length > 2 ? seed : list[i++];
    for(; i < len; i++){
        acc = accumulator(acc, list[i]);
    }
    print(acc);
}
```

This way, you could compute the product of `list` (your method would always return 0):

```
accumulate(list, function(a, b) { return a * b; });
```

**Update**: If you're developing for newer browsers that support ECMAScript 2015 / ES6 (or using a transpiler like Babel), you can also use ['arrow function'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax to make your code a bit more compact:

```
accumulate(list, (a, b) => a * b);
```

Comment: +1 "You can't pass an operator as a parameter, but you can pass a function" was all i needed to get the juices flowing. thanks!

Answer (score 31):

If all the operations you are planning to do are binary operations, then you can do this

```
var operations = {
    "+" : function (operand1, operand2) {
        return operand1 + operand2;
    },
    "-" : function (operand1, operand2) {
        return operand1 - operand2;
    },
    "*" : function (operand1, operand2) {
        return operand1 * operand2;
    }
};

function accumulate(list, operator) {
    return list.reduce(operations[operator]);
}

console.log(accumulate([1, 2, 3, 4], "+"));     // 10
console.log(accumulate([1, 2, 3, 4], "-"));     // -8
console.log(accumulate([1, 2, 3, 4], "*"));     // 24
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you can do that in several different ways, but I would suggest you something like this:

```
var operatorFunction = {
    '+' : function(x, y) {
        return x + y;
    },
    '-' : function(x, y) {
        return x - y;
    },
    '*' : function(x, y) {
        return x * y;
    }
};

function accumul(list, neutral, operator) {
    var sum = neutral;
    list.forEach(function(item) {
        sum = operatorFunction[operator](sum, item);
    });
    return sum;
}

console.log(accumul([2, 3, 4], 0, '+'));
console.log(accumul([2, 3, 4], 0, '-'));
console.log(accumul([2, 3, 4], 1, '*'));
console.log(accumul([], 0, '+'));
console.log(accumul([], 1, '*'));
```

In the example above, you just need something like `accumul([2, 3, 4], 0, '+');` to call you function. `operatorFunction[operator]` calls the correspondent operator function.

Running the example in the command line, with [node.js](http://nodejs.org/), gives:

```
$ node accumulate.js 
9
-9
24
0
1
```

This version also work if the array is empty. You can not use `list.reduce` if the list is empty.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question. Just adding some more information.

If you often use operators and need to [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the results (`accumulate`), it is highly recommended to develop different helpers, so you can quickly use any input form to obtain the results.

Although, this will not be always the case when you use `reduce`, the following helper will allow to pass the first element of your array as `default` value:

```
reducer = (list, func) => list.slice(1).reduce(func, list.slice(0, 1).pop())
```

The above, still has a `function` dependency, so you still need to declare the specific function that wraps your target `operator`:

```
sum = list => reducer(list, (a, b) => a + b)
sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

You could then redefine `sum`, for example, as per new input formats you see will be backwards compatible. In this example by using a new helper, [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) (still experimental as per now; added the code):

```
flat = (e) => Array.isArray(e) ? [].concat.apply([], e.map(flat)) : e

sum = (...list)  => reducer(flat(list), (a, b) => a + b)
mult = (...list) => reducer(flat(list), (a, b) => a * b)

sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

mult([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
mult(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Then you can use `reducer` (or any variant you may find more useful) to simplify the definition of other helpers as well. Just one last example with matrix custom operators (in this case, they are `functions`):

```
zip  = (...lists) => lists[0].map((_l, i) => lists.map(list => list[i]))
dot_product = (a, b) => sum(zip(a, b).map(x => mult(x)))

mx_transpose = (mx) => zip.apply([], mx)
// the operator
mx_product = (m1, m2) =>
    m1.map(row => mx_transpose(m2).map(
         col => dot_product(row, col) ))
// the reducer
mx_multiply = (...mxs) => reducer(mxs, (done, mx) => mx_product(done, mx))

A = [[2, 3, 4],
     [1, 0, 0]]
B = [[0, 1000],
     [1,  100],
     [0,   10]]
C = [[2,   0],
     [0, 0.1]]

JSON.stringify(AB   = mx_product (A,  B))
JSON.stringify(ABC  = mx_product (AB, C))
JSON.stringify(ABC2 = mx_multiply(A, B, C))
```

Answer (score 2):

just pass 1 or -1 as input then multiply all items with this after wh.

Comment: it is simply perfect for my case.

Answer (score 2):

```
var list = { a: 3, b: 7, c: 5 }
var expression = (a) => a * 2;

function computeObject(list, bc){
    for(var x in list){
        list[x] = bc(list[x]);
        console.log(list[x]);
    }
}
computeObject(list, expression);
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done pretty decent using currying:

```js
const calculate = a => str => b => {switch(str) {
  case '+': return a + b
  case '-': return a - b
  case '/': return a / b
  case '*': return a * b
  default: return 'Invalid operation'
}}

const res = calculate(15)('*')(28)

console.log('15 * 28 =', res)
```

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately, its not really possible to do this like you are trying to do. What I would do is pass in a number, and have a if/then or a switch/case to decide what to do based on that number