# Make variable as an operator

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm building a function which gets a variable that includes a mathematic operator, and two random numbers.
I want to return the result of the suitable math action, but I'm not sure how the code should be written.

```
function result(firstnum, secnum, operator) {
return [???];
}
```

Comment: Create an object that maps operator names to functions, then call the function.

Comment: `return operators[operator](firstnum, secnum);`

Comment: take a look at this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/22303786/8414468